# multiple fancybox galleries from one page of thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

I have a page of 6 images each of a different house. When clicked, I want each of these images to open a fancybox gallery of 4 new more detailed images of the same house. Finally I want the 4 detailed photos that are in the fancybox to be shown as thumbnails below the image currently being shown.

I have figured out how to show a fancybox gallery showing the main 6 images (with thumbnails, but I cant for the life of me work out how to make each of the 6 load its own fancybox with the 4 new images in it and its driving me bananas!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of this on the fancybox website:

Title : "Method one - Hide other images (multiple galleries)"

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

Basically you hide the additional ones and group them in galleries using the "rel" grouping for multiple galleries